# OpenGL ES - write code in Windows

Tags: android, iphone, opengl-es2

Is it possible to write application using OpenGL ES 2.0 "emulator" from AMD ([AMD OpenGL ES SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/amd-opengl-es-sdk/)) and then use the same code (compile again, of course) in my iOS / Android / Whatever application ? The point is, that I write code faster in Visual Studio (where I have some fancy tools). Is it possible to do it that way ?

An second subquestion. So far, I have no experience with OpenGL, I know DX 9/11. Is there a big change (besside initialization) in those APIs in term of "learn basics of OpenGL if I know DX pretty well".

Comment: These are two very different questions and should not be asked together. Why would you doubt the AMD OpenGL ES SDK, if the linked web page says that it provides what you are looking for?

Comment: @msell One thing is what they claim it does, experience is another thing :) Like develping without real device only with emulator. Sometimes it does something different way and than it takes a long time to find problem. In graphics, it would be bigger problem than with some GUI. So I wanted some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/ES2_compatibility.txt)

> This extension adds support for features of OpenGL ES 2.0 that are missing from OpenGL 3.x.

While the intention behind this is to assist porting apps from ES2 to GL3, there seems no reason why it can't be used the other way too.  So long as you strictly confine yourself to the common subset, you'll come out the other end with valid ES2 code.

Note of course that this will only apply to your *rendering* code.  You're going to have a *lot* of other platform-specific code (sound, input, possibly networking, window management, etc) that will also need to be tackled, but that's nothing to do with either OpenGL or ES.

Comment: Yeah.. thanks. My concern was only graphics. Other is more or less platform specific.